# How to use the variable inside some function?

Tags: php

I have an API's Function :

```
$transaction=$tran[4];
function coinpayments_api_call($cmd, $req = array(),$transaction) { 
curl_init($transaction);
}
```

$transaction variable not passing into function coinpayments_api_call.

function not taking values from out side.

I also make $transaction varible GLOBAL ,but still same problem ,

Please Help

Comment: why not you pass that when call the function

Comment: You are missing ; in this linecurl_init($transaction);

Comment: "function not taking values from out side". Well no, that's not how it works. Have a read about PHP scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

Make your code like this

```
$transaction=$tran[4];
function coinpayments_api_call($transaction,$cmd, $req = array(),$txnid) { 
curl_init($transaction);
}
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in this code of missing semicolon from this line curl_init($transaction);

Comment: Yes i have corrected.